# Is it possible to know if a topic is latched on subscriber side in cpp

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to figure out if a topic is latched on the subscriber side in cpp.
This is needed to implement a feature in rosbag-snapshot.
Is that possible and if yes any hints how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369433/is-it-possible-to-know-if-a-topic-is-latched-on-subscriber-side-in-cpp/) by [arneboe](https://answers.ros.org/users/67789/arneboe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about doing this in C++ specifically, but at least the [Connection header](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Connection%20Header) appears to have a field which encodes whether:

> publisher is in latching mode (i.e. sends the last value published to new subscribers)

The [wiki/rospy/Overview/Publishers and Subscribers: Subscribing to a topic - Connection Information](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Connection_Information) shows how to access this in `rospy`.

In `roscpp`, you can get the header from the [MessageEvent](https://docs.ros.org/en/api/roscpp_traits/html/classros_1_1MessageEvent.html) (`getConnectionHeader()`, via [MessageEvent [ROS 1.1+]](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#MessageEvent_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D)).

I would expect `rosbag` to have other options to get the connection header though, seeing as it already deals with connections.

---

Edit: [this comment](https://github.com/ros/rosbag_snapshot/issues/6#issuecomment-666364534) in the issue you commented on links to [ros/ros_comm/tools/topic_tools/src/relay.cpp](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/f781defbf6f46ced0d940bea2ac977e18238586b/tools/topic_tools/src/relay.cpp#L92) which actually shows how to do this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<const ros::M_string> const& connection_header =
  msg_event.getConnectionHeaderPtr();

[..]

// If the input topic is latched, make the output topic latched, #3385.
bool latch = false;
if (connection_header)
{
  ros::M_string::const_iterator it = connection_header->find("latching");
  if((it != connection_header->end()) && (it->second == "1"))
  {
    ROS_DEBUG("input topic is latched; latching output topic to match");
    latch = true;
  }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1